# Create plot and display it later without save it with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I stocked images in a dict like this and I would like to display them later but I don't know how to do. For now I do this :

```
for k in dataT:
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
    f_k=dataT.plot.scatter(x=xcol,y=ycol,c=k,cmap=rainbow,ax=ax)
    Figure_saving[str(k)]=f_k
    plt.close()
```

And then I would like call a figure at place k in my dict and display it, I try a lot and stuff but specially this and it doesn't work :

```
plt.show(Figure_saving[k])
```

Does someone have an idea?
Thanks,

Comment: I don't think this will work, because matplotlib is a state machine. You may want to save the plots as pdf and the load the pdf later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a plot and display it later I would be making it in its own function.

Example:

```
def createPlot():
   for k in dataT:
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
    f_k=dataT.plot.scatter(x=xcol,y=ycol,c=k,cmap=rainbow,ax=ax)
    Figure_saving[str(k)]=f_k
    plt.close()
```

This way you can display the graph every time you call the function.